# How to execute JSX file in vanilla JS with Babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I want to import a JSX file in vanilla JS and execute it so that I get an actual Component object. I tried to do this with Babel, but it only gives me code as a string, it doesn't execute it. I don't want to eval because it's nonstandard and relative dir strings aren't changed.

I'm currently trying

```js
const babel = require('@babel/core')

  babel.transformFileAsync('./src/Page.jsx', {
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'
    ]
  })
    .then((parsed) => {
      const page = React.createElement(eval(parsed.code), {
        classes: db.classes
      })
    })
```

However, my `import './styles/Page.css'` which I have in the JSX file fails as that relative path is incorrect in the file it's being eval'd in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these packages for css and styling?

```
// npm
npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader
// yarn
yarn add --dev css-loader style-loader
```

You can read more about how to use Webpack and Babel with Vanila JS [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/why-and-how-to-use-webpack-and-babel-with-vanilla-js.aspx).

Comment: The article you linked talks about using Webpack CLI. How do I use Webpack in Node? (Up until now I've been trying to just render using Babel)

Comment: Here's how you can use webpack with babel https://www.robinwieruch.de/webpack-babel-setup-tutorial/.

Comment: Apologies, but either I'm being unclear or not understanding. These articles are setting up Babel to work with Webpack in the Webpack config. I'm asking how to build with Webpack in a Node script rather than the Webpack command line interface

Comment: Yes, you should intall webpack with npm and customize it as you need

Comment: How do I bundle with Webpack in NodeJS instead of the command line?? The NPM package of Webpack is for running the `webpack` command. I do not want that. I want functions I can run in Node. In a `.js` file